# (AMC$12$A $2005$) Problem involving Number Systems.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:**[image]

**My Attempt:** I observed that $000000-000050$ amounts to $36$ miles, then $000050-000100$ amounts to $45$ miles, $000100-000150$ amounts to $36$ miles, $000150-000200$ amounts to $45$ miles, and so on and concluded that the answer should be $81*20+4=1624.$ But the correct answer is $1462.$ Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you relabel the digits of the odometer so that:

$$
0 \mapsto 0 \\
1 \mapsto 1 \\
2 \mapsto 2 \\
3 \mapsto 3 \\
$$
$$
5 \mapsto 4 \\
6 \mapsto 5 \\
7 \mapsto 6 \\
8 \mapsto 7 \\
9 \mapsto 8 \\
$$

Then the current reading would show $2004$, and the odometer would have counted correctly in base $9$ up to that number. So the number of miles is $2004_9 = 1462$.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier if you realize that this is just base 9, using the digits 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, and 9. So 2005 is 2*9^3 + 4*9^0, where 2 is the 2nd digit after 0 and 5 is the 4th digit after 0.